# "Could not" or "was not able to"

Tags: modal-verbs, periphrastic-modals

If I'm trying to describe a situation in the past in which I wasn't able to find a specific pair of shoes, should I say:

> 1. I couldn't find those ones.

or

> 2. I wasn't able to find those ones.

Comment: Same thing. They mean the same in practical terms.

Comment: Not really. See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/122339/71740) if you want something a bit more exhaustive. (You asked a fairly specific question, but perhaps you could generalize some of its aspects to get a more reference-like answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, "can" and "be able to" are interchangeable. But be careful, because there are subtle differences.

For example, your question start with "Can I use..." - this is an example of using "can" with the meaning "is allowed to". Consequently, "can you do it?" may have a very different meaning from "are you able to do it?", and sometimes you should choose your words carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either.

> I **could not** find *something*.
>   I **was not able** to find *something*.

"***Can***" means *ability*.